# Is it possible to get a correlation value greater than 1?

Tags: correlation, standard-deviation, pre-post-comparison

I am conducting a meta-analysis on a series of studies without a control group, with pre-and-‎postoperative data (Mean ± SD). I have calculated the SD of the mean change using the reported p-value ‎for the paired t-test in each study. Now, the problem is that the estimated pre-post correlation gives a ‎value outside the range of -1 to +1, in some studies. For example, the data of a study is as follows: ‎N=115; Preoperative mean= 13.4 ± 0.7; Postoperative mean= 12.8 ± 0.8; P = 0.758 paired t-test. Here, ‎the SD of the change ‎ according to‎ the above p-value would be 20.8, and then, by plugging the values of ‎SD in this equation $Corr=(SD_{pre}^2  + SD_{post}^2- SD_{change}^2)/(2 × SD_{pre} ×‎‎ SD_{post})$, the pre-post correlation‎  would be -386.5.
How to justify these results? Am I wrong in my ‎calculations?‎

Comment: I formatted your question using LaTeX.  Please check that I did not mess up.

Where did you get the formula? It seems wrong, and the result is surely wrong.

Comment: Your formula does not make sense. All of your standard deviations have units, and the dimensional analysis says that the output of this formula has units, which correlation should not. What do you intend to calculate, where did you get that formula, and how did you get that standard deviation of $20.8?$

Comment: @Dave Analysis in terms of units or dimensions gives me that the "dimensions" of the correlatiion are variance / variance, which cancel fine, regardless of the units of any variable.

Comment: ‎1) t-statistic = t.inv.2t (p-value, deg of freedom)⇛ t.inv.2t(0.758,114) = 0.3088‎
‎2) MD = Mpre – Mpost = 13.4 – 12.8 = 0.6‎
‎3) t-value = MD ÷ SE ⇛ SE = MD ÷ t-value ⇛ SE = 0.6 ÷ 0.3088 = 1.94‎
‎4) SD = SE × sqrt(N) ⇛ SD =1.94 × sqrt(115) = 20.83‎

Answer (score 2):

Let's start from the usual formulas
$$\text{Corr}(X,Y)=\mathrm{cov}[X,Y]/\sqrt{\mathrm{var}[X]\mathrm{var}[Y]}$$
We also have (assuming $X$ and $Y$ are in the same units and subtraction makes sense)
$$\mathrm{var}[X-Y]=\mathrm{var}[X]+\mathrm{var}[Y]-2\ \mathrm{cov}[X,Y]$$
so
$$2\ \mathrm{cov}[X,Y]=\mathrm{var}[X]+\mathrm{var}[Y]-\mathrm{var}[X-Y]$$
and
$$2\ \text{Corr}(X,Y)=(\mathrm{var}[X]+\mathrm{var}[Y]-\mathrm{var}[X-Y])/\sqrt{\mathrm{var}[X]\mathrm{var}[Y]}$$
or
$$\text{Corr}(X,Y)=\frac{\mathrm{var}[X]+\mathrm{var}[Y]-\mathrm{var}[X-Y]}{2\ \sqrt{\mathrm{var}[X]}\sqrt{\mathrm{var}[Y]}}.$$
So, despite the aspersions being cast by some, your formula is correct.

Now let's look at the change.  The p-value of $0.758$ implies a $Z$-statistic of $-0.308$, and with a difference of 0.6 on a sample size of 115 this means the standard deviation of the difference is

```
> -0.6*sqrt(115)/qnorm(0.758/2)
[1] 20.88319
```

That's impossible if the pre- and post- standard deviations are 0.7 and 0.8 as you say. The correlation would then have to be bigger than 1.

The most plausible explanation seemed to be a confusion of standard error of the mean and standard deviation.  If the standard error of the mean pre- and post- were 0.7 and 0.8, the standard error of the mean difference would be

```
> -0.6/qnorm(0.758/2)
[1] 1.947368
```

and the correlation would be

```
> (0.7^2+0.8^2-1.94^2)/(2*0.7*0.8)
[1] -2.351429
```

which is still wrong.

So, it looks as though your data are wrong.  If the $p$-value were 0.0758 instead of 0.758 the data would be possible.